Can the simulation box's edge length differ from the periodic distance in an Lennard-Jones (LJ) Monte-Carlo (MC) simulation?
I am performing a Monte-Carlo (MC) simulation using the Lennard-Jones (LJ) potential.
Based on my understanding:

The length of the simulation box's edge, $L$, is defined as:
$$L = \left( \frac{N}{\rho} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
where:

$N$: Number of particles (or beads) in the system
$\rho$: Number density


$L$ also corresponds to the periodic distance, i.e., the maximum length before positions wrap around due to periodic boundary conditions.


Question:
Could there be any scenario in an MC simulation where a cubic simulation box's edge length $L$ is different from the periodic distance (the length used to calculate minimum image conventions or wrap coordinates)?

Any is pretty broad, ex. surface studies are necessarily non-periodic in one direction and thus, have no periodic distance. If you're simulating amorphous materials, then you have no periodic distance as well. In general, any finite system (like a protein molecule) would not have such a periodic distance.
The length of the simulation box is a parameter that you set to define the domain of interest, which sufficiently includes the interactions of interest to you (ex. $L>r_c$ where $r_c$ is the LJ cutoff radius). For crystals, we normally use the crystal period when you conduct bulk studies, where all internal potentials have the same period as well.
Edit: My point is that your simulation box's dimensions are dependent on the system and interactions you want to analyze. The simulation box is the region where your MD program computes interactions explicitly, then you use appropriate boundary conditions (BC) to generalize those computations over large length scales. If you have periodic BC, then a mismatch in your system and simulation box periodicity would perform unnecessary (and mainly expensive) computation, since some of your explicit calculations are just trivially identical due to your system's periodicity. You want to use the smallest simulation box which sufficiently includes all the regions of interest and uses all underlying system symmetries to reduce explicit computations. In crystals, as you'll guess, a lot of the explicit computations are reduced if you use simulation boxes with periods which are multiples of the crystal period. If you were modeling crystalline sulphur at room conditions, its orthorhombic. If you were modeling rutile crystals, it would be tetragonal.

Any is pretty broad, --- I have edited the question to limit it to cubic simulation boxes.
